# Is it possible to make DateBox work in time-zone other than in one that is set in browser?

Tags: gwt, datetimepicker, gwt2

Is it possible to make [DateBox](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/datepicker/client/DateBox.html) work in time-zone other than in one that is set in browser ?

In my case time-zone should change depending on other information in form.

Based on info in the documentation there is no built-in way to do that. Could you suggest how you would approach it ?

Answer (score 4):

I did this by creating a class implementing DateBox.Format: -

```
public class MyDateFormat implements DateBox.Format
{

    private TimeZone tz;

    public MyDateFormat(TimeZone tz)
    {
        this.tz = tz;
    }

    @Override
    public String format(DateBox arg0, Date arg1)
    {
        if(arg1 == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss Z").format(arg1, tz);
    }

    @Override
    public Date parse(DateBox arg0, String arg1, boolean arg2)
    {
        return DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss Z").parse(arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public void reset(DateBox arg0, boolean arg1)
    {

    }
}
```

and then: -

```
dateBox.setFormat(new MyDateFormat(tz));
```